# Rockstar games : GTA 5, GTA 4 etc. bought games, can we download games data from Rockstar somehow?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, rockstar-games-social-club

I have few Games like GTA 4, Gta 5 ect. from Rockstar Games, is there a way i can download the game data(Actual Game Installation Data) from Rockstar's website like Ubisoft provides with thier UPlay: where i can download purchased games if i am logged in some other system?

I did purchased DVDs of these games, and i presently do not have them on me. So i was looking for a way to install these games into my new System somehow.

Comment: The only method I've found so far is via [their website](https://www.rockstargames.com/downloads/collection/11), but you can only download the files if you've bought the game digitally through Rockstar Warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For GTA 5 purchased on a disk (so only attached to your Rockstar Social club Account):

Note that you will have to have installed and registered the game license from the disks at least once before this process. Go to the Rockstar Social Club website:

https://socialclub.rockstargames.com/

Then sign in with your Rockstar Social Club credentials. If you attached a social media account to your RSSC account, you can also sign in using the relevant service, which could be easier if you are already logged into that service.

Once you're signed in, go to the top right icon that represents your RSSC avatar (default the Rockstar R), and click Game Downloads in that menu. you are presented a list of games, and the first game should be GTA V. you can click download to download the installer. then after you downloaded and ran the installer, you can start the launcher and download the rest of the game (about 70-80 GB last time I checked).

It is possible that GTA IV purchased on a disk can also be downloaded through this method, but I'm not entirely sure how that works because I own my copy on Steam and haven't had to do the disk install in years.